# React Native Maps Slow Rendering of Markers

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-maps

So I'm having an issue with `react-native-maps` chugging when run on device or on simulator in `release` configuration. On `debug` (device and simulator) the map works great; it's responsive, controls well, etc etc. On `release`, it can't seem to handle rendering multiple `<MapView.Marker/>` components (and when I say multiple I don't mean hundreds or thousands, I mean < 20).

Here's a sample of the code:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        currentPosition: global.currentPosition,
        orders: [],
        coordinateArray: []
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.handleOrders().then(() => {
        this.setMapToCoordinates();
    });
}

async handleOrders() {
    let result = await data.fetchData("...");
    if (result) {
        let orders = [];
        let coordinateArray = [];

        result.data_list.forEach(orderObject => {
            let order = {
                coordinates: orderParser.constructCoordinates(orderObject),
            };
            coordinateArray.push(order.coordinates);
            orders.push(order);
        });

        this.setState({
            orders: orders,
            coordinateArray: coordinateArray
        });
    }
}

setMapToCoordinates(){
    if (this.mapView) {
        let coordinateArray = this.state.coordinateArray;
        if (this.state.currentPosition) {
            coordinateArray = coordinateArray.concat(this.state.currentPosition.coordinates);
        }
        this.mapView.fitToCoordinates(coordinateArray, {
            edgePadding: {
                top: 200,
                right: 100,
                bottom: 100,
                left: 100
            },
            animated: animated
        });
    }
}
```

So, what happens in this code is that when the component mounts, it performs an API call to fetch a bunch of `orders`, which contain `coordinates`, along with other information. In addition to pushing this to `orders`, it pushes the coordinates to `coordinateArray`, which is used in `setMapToCoordinates()` to constrain the map bounds.

Next, here is the `render` function of this component:

```
render() {
    return (
        <MapView mapType="satellite" ref={ref => { if (!this.mapView) { this.mapView = ref; }}}>
            {this.state.orders.map(order => {
                return <MapView.Marker key={order.id} coordinate={order.coordinates} image={require("...")} />;
            })}
            {this.state.currentPosition ? <MapView.Marker key={"currentPosition"} coordinate={this.state.currentPosition.coordinates} image={require("../images/pin.png")} centerOffset={{ x: 0, y: -25 }} /> : null}
        </MapView>
    );
}
```

And this is the flow of actions:

1. Component mounts, rendering `<MapView>` and a single `<MapView.Marker/>` for `this.state.currentPosition` (retrieved in earlier component)
2. `handleOrders()` is called, updating `this.state.orders` and `this.state.coordinateArray`.
3. Additional `<MapView.Marker/>` components are rendered.
4. `setMapToCoordinates()` is called, moving the map to fit both `this.state.currentPosition` and `this.state.coordinateArray` into view.

On `debug`, there is no issue in this workflow, but on `release`, there is a ~40 second delay between the success of step 2 and the completion of step 3. Following the successful render of these ~16 markers, everything proceeds to work correctly, but during that loading time, the app is completely non-responsive. Also, since there is navigation involved, this flow is called multiple times in a single session.

If anyone knows the cause of this issue and/or how to fix it, that would be great. I'm having a very difficult time debugging this as in `release` scheme, logging is disabled.

For further reference:

- `react-native-maps: ^0.17.1`
- `react-native: 0.49.3`
- `release` scheme
- iPhone 6, 7 and 7+ tested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, not shown in my code above is a simple logging statement

```
setMapToCoordinates(){
    console.log("Called!", this.mapView);
    ...
}
```

I was using this to test what `this.mapView` was in a couple different situations, and in `debug` configuration, it logged `"Called!", ...` with no issue (`this.mapView` is set as a `ref` on `<MapView>`).

For some reason, in `release` configuration, this piece of code causes massive slowdown when calling `this.setMapToCoordinates()`, which happens following the API call to fetch `orders`, along with other actions.

So while I can't answer the "why" of this issue, I can answer the "how", and if someone else comes across something similar, maybe this can help them.

Comment: I believe your observation is correct. In React-Native official document (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html#using-consolelog-statements), it also states that console.log can cause heavy performance issues.

Comment: Interesting; wouldn't have though this was an issue with React Native itself, but nice find regardless. Will definitely consider that for future projects.